# Use JQUERY/JSON to auto fill select dropdown boxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

OK I spent spent a lot of time looking over examples but can't find one which helps me enough for my situation. I have a JSON file, simplified for this example:

```
{
 "Company":[
    {
        "Position": "Manager",
        "Name": {
                            "11": "joe",
                            "12": "bill",
                            "166": "John"
                            }
    },
{

        "Position": "Tech",
        "Name": {
                            "11": "Bob",
                            "12": "Cindy",
                            "166": "Karl"
                            }
    },
{

        "Position": "Sales",
        "Name": {
                            "11": "Sam",
                            "12": "Ron",
                            "166": "Sara"
                            }
    }
]}
```

I am trying to create 2 select boxes. When the user selects the first box of positions, it will auto-fill the second with the attributes (names). So here is what I have so far:

```
<select id="job"></select>
<select id="name"></select>
```

and the code:

```
$select = $('#job');
$select2 = $('#name');

$.ajax({
    url: 'factors.json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {

        $select.html('');
        $.each(data.Company, function(key, val) {
            $select.append('<option id="' + key + '">' + val.Position + '</option>');



            $("#job").change(function() {
                $.each(val.Name, function(key2, val2) {
                    $select2.append('<option id="' + key2 + '">' + val2 + '</option>');
                })
            })
        })
    },
});​
```

This code will autofill the second box with ALL the names in every position. I jsut can't seem to figure out how to fill it with the names of each unique object. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You JSON is invalid as it is

Comment: Opp sorry - I missed the closing brackets when slimming it down for this post. Shouldbe ok now

Comment: Still invalid, you have trailing commas

Comment: just noticed that too.. I think I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$.each(data.Company, function(key, val) {
    $select.append('<option id="' + key + '">' + val.Position + '</option>');
});



$("#job").change(function(e) {
    $select2.empty();
    $index = $(this).children(':selected').attr('id');
        for (var k in data.Company[$index].Name) {
            $select2.append('<option id="' + k + '">' + data.Company[$index].Name[k] + '</option>');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  You should really have a value property for your options.  I added a data-id attr to the options so I can use that to store the index of Position.

```
$.each(data.Company, function(i, v) {
    // create option with value as index - makes it easier to access on change
    var options = $('<option/>', {value: v.Position, text: v.Position}).attr('data-id',i);    
    // append the options to job selectbox
    $('#job').append(options);
});

// bind change event
$('#job').change(function() {
    // cache this
    var $el = $(this);
    // get data-id attr from selected option
    var id = $('option:selected',this).data('id');
    // empty select
    $('#name').empty();
    // get name values for selected option
    $.each(data.Company[id].Name, function(i, v) {
        // create option elements
        var options = $('<option/>', {value: v, text: v});
        // append the options to name selectbox
        $('#name').append(options);
    });    
}).change();// trigger change() on page load to fill name selectbox​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/xYX8z/

Comment: Thank you - this helps me understand how to get this in a different way!