# how to reload html dropdown box using jquery code?

Tags: jquery, html

```
$("#statelist").change(function() {
            //loadCities(this.value);
            $.ajax({
                url : "getCities.html",
                dataType : "json",
                data : "stateId="+this.value, 
                type : "get",
                cache : false,
                success : function(data){
                    var citiesList=data.citiesBo;
                    loadCities(citiesList);
                }
            });
            function loadCities(citiesList) {
                $("#citylist option[value!='-1']").remove();
                //citiesList = citiesMap[index];
                $.each(citiesList, function(index, item) {
                    $("#citylist").append($("<option></option>").text(item.name).val(item.cityId));
                });
                return true;
            };
        });

    $("#citylist").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url : "getAreas.html",
            dataType : "json",
            data : "cityId="+this.value, 
            type : "get",
            cache : false,
            success : function(data){
                var areasList=data.areasBo;
                loadAreas(areasList);
            }
        });
        function loadAreas(areasList) {
            $("#arealist option[value!='-1']").remove();
            //citiesList = citiesMap[index];
            $.each(areasList, function(index, area) {
                $("#arealist").append($("<option></option>").text(area.name).val(area.areaId));
            });
            return true;
        };
    });


});`I have three dropdown boxes  like States, city, area.
```

I was select the state , the city was reload , then i am select the city the area was reload after i am change the state the city only reload , the area was append on same selected value.
how to reload at same time?

First i was select state:Karnataga
City:Bengolure
Area:Majestic

After i am select state:Tamil nadu 
city : Select city
But area is Majestic is appear same .

i am using change event for state city changes

I want to reload city and area dropdown box value when i am select and change the state value

Comment: I'm confused, what are you asking?

Comment: The code you're using would be nice to see. You need to add a reset to the area dropdown when changing the state dropdown.

Comment: Yes Niklas, i want to change two dropdown box like city and area

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use JQUERY/JSON to auto fill select dropdown boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272187/use-jquery-json-to-auto-fill-select-dropdown-boxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these methods mentioned here : [Use JQUERY/JSON to auto fill select dropdown boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272187/use-jquery-json-to-auto-fill-select-dropdown-boxes)

But without knowing how you are populating the data its a bit difficult to suggest a solution.