# Populate extra drop-down based on selection

Tags: php, jquery

first of all this code works like a charm, my question is to add a feature.
I would like to know how can I populate next drop down based on selection. so for example I select first stock 'US500' and it would show me prices on second drop-down. how can I do this?

data.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['getlist']))
{
    $list = $_GET['getlist'];
    $qry='';
    switch($list)
    {
        case 'tracks':
        {
            $qry = "SELECT TABLE_NAME as allStocks FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_stocks' AND TABLE_ROWS > 100";
            break;
        }
    }
    if(empty($qry)){ echo "invalid params! "; exit; }

    $dbconn = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass') 
            or die("DB login failed!");

    mysql_select_db('db_nadex_stocks', $dbconn) 
            or die("Database does not exist! ".mysql_error($dbconn));

    $result = mysql_query($qry,$dbconn)
            or die("Query $qry failed! ".mysql_error($dbconn));

    $rows = array();

    while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $rows[] = $rec;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($dbconn);

    echo json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>List Sample 1</title>
<style>
body{ font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 1em;}
h1 {font-size : 18pt;   color : #000066;}
h2 {font-size : 14pt;   color : #000066;}
a:hover{text-decoration : none;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadlist(selobj,url,nameattr) {
        $(selobj).empty();
        $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(i,obj)
            {
                $(selobj).append($('<option></option>').val(obj[nameattr]).html(obj[nameattr]));
            });
        });
    }

    $(function() { 
       loadlist($('select#sel1').get(0), 'data.php?getlist=tracks','allStocks');
       loadlist($('select#sel2').get(0), 'data.php?getlist=tracks','allStocks');
       loadlist($('select#sel3').get(0), 'data.php?getlist=tracks','allStocks');
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Dynamically lists: multiple lists</h1>
<p>
dfgdgf 1:<select name='sdfsdf' id='sel1' size='1'></select>
</p>
<p>
cvbcvb 2:<select name='sdfsdf' id='sel2' size='1'></select>
</p>
<p>
cvbcv 3:<select name='dfgdfg' id='sel3' size='1'></select>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use JQUERY/JSON to auto fill select dropdown boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272187/use-jquery-json-to-auto-fill-select-dropdown-boxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add in an onChange to the first dropdown and then send the selected index of the first dropdown to the same function. Something like this in the onChange.

```
loadlist($('select#sel2').get(0), 'data.php?getlist=prices&stock_id=' + $(this).val(),'allStocks');
```

And then add into the switch statement a check for 'prices' and **query** for the prices using the stock_id

```
$_GET['stock_id']
```

Comment: Take a look at the link Patrick Q commented on your original post. This describes what needs to be done. You still need to code your new select statement that grabs the prices. If something isn't working be more descriptive.. post what you have added.. post what error you are getting... saying that it isn't working doesn't tell me or anyone else anything.